# Null and Empty check using Elvis Operator

Tags: kotlin

I have:

`return if(mValue== null || mValue.asString.isNullOrEmpty()) "Home" else mValue.asString`

I tried to perform Elvis operator:

`return mValue?.asString ?: "Home"`

But I also want to check for *empty* case for `mValue` as well.

So if `mValue` is either null or if it's empty, I want to return "Home" else return its content in String, without using `when` or `if`.

Thank you!

Comment: try using `isNullOrEmpty()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot actually use elvis operator for the case if the String is empty. According to [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) elvis operator is only used to check whether a variable is null or not. Therefore, I would suggest you using:

```
return if (mValue.isNullOrEmpty()) "Home" else mValue
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This answers my question! 
I can't force Elvis operator do what it can't.

Answer (score 6):

You could combine [`orEmpty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/or-empty.html) and [`ifEmpty`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/if-empty.html):

```
return mValue?.asString.orEmpty().ifEmpty { "Home" }
```

Whether that's an improvment or not, I don't know.

Comment: What is `asString`? I like your solution but have no idea what that method is... I would use something like `(mValue as String?)...`

Comment: I've no idea what `asString` is. OP used it in their question, so I assumed it was a property of whatever `mValue` is.

Comment: This is good, but why is `orEmpty()` needed?  Wouldn't `ifEmpty` work?

Comment: The question asked for a solution where a default value is returned if the input string is either `null` or empty. So the idea here was to use `orEmpty()` to convert any `null`-values to empty strings, and then use `ifEmpty` to replace empty strings with the default value.